# Django template tag url doesn't work

Tags: django, url

I get this error which is caused by the URL template tag:

In template C:\Users\Don't Panic\BitNami DjangoStack projects\Templates\polls\index.html, error at line 5

I really don't know why it does that. I tried removing that line and it works fine so I think that's the only one causing the trouble.

(BTW i'm in Django 1.4.1)

Also I've already tried removing the quotes and removing the first line and all combinations of those. Help me?

```
    1   {% load url from future %}
    2   {% if latest_poll_list %}
    3       <ul>
    4       {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    5           <li><a href="{% url 'polls.views.detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    6       {% endfor %}
    7       </ul>
    8   {% else %}
    9       <p>No polls are available</p>
    10  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Always post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 5):

if you have like this in `urls.py`

```
app_name = 'polls' 

 url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

than you guys have to do code like this

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

**here polls is namespace**

`app_name = 'polls'`
is namespace here 
so don't get confused with app name that we are registering in `setting.py`

Answer (score -1):

In line

```
5           <li><a href="{% url 'polls.views.detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

i will recommend you to define a name in your urls.py for `'polls.views.detail`  and use that name here like

urls.py

```
url(r^yoururl,'polls.views.detail',name = somename)
```

now use like

```
           <li><a href="{% url 'somename' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
```

hope this will help you